# Concatenating strings in a column according to values in another column in a dataframe

Tags: string, r, dataframe, concatenation

I have a `data.frame` with two columns of strings as follows.

```
nos <- c("JM1", "JM2", "JM3", "JM1", "JM5", "JM45", "JM3", "JM45")
ren <- c("book, vend, spent", "marigold, fortune", "smoke, parchment, smell, book", "mental, past, create", "key, fortune, mask, federal", "tell, warn, slip", "wire, dg333, uv12", "tell, warn, slip, furniture")
d <- data.frame(nos, ren, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

d
   nos                           ren
1  JM1             book, vend, spent
2  JM2             marigold, fortune
3  JM3 smoke, parchment, smell, book
4  JM1          mental, past, create
5  JM5   key, fortune, mask, federal
6 JM45              tell, warn, slip
7  JM3             wire, dg333, uv12
8 JM45   tell, warn, slip, furniture
```

I want to concatenate the elements of `ren` column according to the strings in `nos` column.

For example in the sample data, the elements associated with JM1 which occurs twice should be merged ("book, vend, spent, mental, past, create").

Also the elements associated with JM45 should be merged keeping only unique words. ("tell, warn, slip, furniture")

The output that I am trying to get is like below.

```
nos1 <- c("JM1", "JM2", "JM3", "JM5", "JM45")
ren1 <- c("book, vend, spent, mental, past, create", "marigold, fortune", "smoke, parchment, smell, book, wire, dg333, uv12", "key, fortune, mask, federal", "tell, warn, slip, furniture")
out <- data.frame(nos1, ren1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

out
  nos1                                             ren1
1  JM1          book, vend, spent, mental, past, create
2  JM2                                marigold, fortune
3  JM3 smoke, parchment, smell, book, wire, dg333, uv12
4  JM5                      key, fortune, mask, federal
5 JM45                      tell, warn, slip, furniture
```

How to do this in `R`? My original data set has thousands of such rows in a `data.frame`.

Comment: The question is, *why* are you storing your data like this? A `list` seems like it would make more sense, or a "long" dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `plyr` package you could do it like this

```
ddply(d, .(nos), summarise, ren1=paste0(ren, collapse=", "))
```

or if you want unique values in `ren1` like this

```
ddply(d, .(nos), summarise, 
      paste0(unique(unlist(strsplit(ren, split=", "))), collapse=", "))
```

Comment: +1. Or `aggregate`, "dplyr", "data.table", `tapply` and so on :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto How can I do this with `aggregate` of `tapply`?

Comment: @Crops, `aggregate(ren ~ nos, d, paste, collapse = ", ")` should do it.

Comment: @Crops, and, for `tapply`, you should be able to do `with(d, tapply(ren, nos, paste, collapse = ", "))` (but that would probably just give you a named vector).

Comment: Will data.table be faster with large datasets?

Comment: If you want speed then you should use `data.table` or `dplyr`

Comment: @Crops, it should definitely be, but again, how are you going to use this data later on? There really might be better forms to store your data. I've written a few functions exactly to undo what you're trying to do here because I don't find this form of data to be very useful.

Comment: @AnandaMahto the comma seperated strings in ren column are extracted from different parts of JMxyz long fields as a single string only based on specific flanking characters. But you are right, a list would be better.

Comment: @iugrina plyr is working fine, but How can I do this with data.table?